# For which values of a and b is the set of vectors linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

If the vectors $X, Y,$ and $Z$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are linearly dependent, then for which a,b $\in \mathbb{R}$ will the vectors $X, aX+Y,$ and $bY + Z$ also be linearly dependent?

I tried doing this: $c_1X + c_2(aX+Y) + c_3(bY+Z) = 0$ and showing that at least one $c_i \neq 0$, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix $A$ whose columns are $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. Then its clear that the matrix $B$ whose columns are $X$, $aX + Y$, and $bY + Z$ can be written as $CA$, where $C$ takes the form 
$$C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & a & 0 \\
0 & 1 & b \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Note that the columns of a matrix are linearly dependent if and only if its determinant is zero. This would mean that $\det(A) = 0$, and hence $\det(CA) = \det(C)\det(A) = 0$. Hence, the columns of $B$, which are the vectors that you are interested in, must be linearly dependent.